# Checking input con2d

Tags: python-3.x

```
I am new to ML I receive the error when I try to fit my model. I am trying to train a cat classifier.
```

Defining the new model

```
 model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
                  metrics=['acc'])

    # All images will be rescaled by 1./255
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    # Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_dir,  # This is the source directory for training images
            target_size=(250, 250),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
            batch_size=20,
            # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
            class_mode='binary')
```

Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                validation_dir,
                target_size=(250, 250),
                batch_size=20,
                class_mode='binary')

Fir the model on data

```
    history = model.fit_generator(
          train_generator,
          steps_per_epoch=100,  # 2000 images = batch_size * steps
          epochs=100,
          validation_data=validation_generator,
          validation_steps=50,  # 1000 images = batch_size * steps
          verbose=2)
```

Here I am trying to fit the model but I end up with an error of input. Please check where did I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be removed if you do 2 changes at your code here:

target_size=(150, 150) even your comment say so. So why you are trying to use 250 I don't understand